# Using memmove to move element in array

Tags: c

I allocated a multi-dimensional array using malloc. After I process an element I have to delete it from the array and reallocate the correct amount of memory. So I used memmove to overwrite the array moving the elements that are in the next position with respect to the one I processed in its position.

```
float **dataset = (float**)malloc(CHUNK * sizeof(float *));

for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; i++) {
    dataset[i] = (float *) malloc((d + 1) * sizeof(float));
    if(dataset[i] == NULL){
        printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), memory allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
}

 [... filling the dataset and other stuff...]

/* now I want to move all the elements from the second one, 
back of 1 position and then reallocate dataset 
to have one less dimensoin*/ 

memmove(dataset[0], dataset[1], 20 * sizeof(float*));
```

But it only moves the first 4 elements.

Comment: "multi-dimensional array using" You allocated an array of pointers, not a multidimensional array. How is fixed value `20` related to `CHUNK`?

Comment: If you want to move the pointers stored in `dataset` you need to pass the address to `memmove`: `memmove(&dataset[0], &dataset[1], ...)` Otherwise you will copy the data where each pointer points to which would only be 1 `float`, not 20

Comment: To clarify if your code is wrong or your description of what you are doing, you might add some illustration how your memory layout should look according to your plan.

Comment: @Gerhardh, CHUNK = 20, I forgot to change it when I pasted, I did it to make you understand that it doesn't move 20 but only 4 elements. However, you give me the right solution, thank you!

Comment: 20 is one too much, then. You only want to move 19. If you copy wrong data with wrong size it might look as if only 4 were moved while something completely different happened.